VS2022 Error in Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output.2.4.4
I use Visual Studio 2022 with a Project with multiple nuget packages.
All errors are solved and the project should be compiled successfully.
Now i get the error:

"PackageRetrievalTask -
System.ArgumentException->Microsoft.Build.Framework.BuildException.GenericBuildTransferredException:
The partial URI must not begin with two slashes"

I dont know where to find these two slashes.
The Path of the exception is:

"ProjectPath\packages\Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output.2.4.4\build\Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output.targets(65,5):
error MSB4018"

The Code in the Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output.targets(65,5) is:

PackageRetrievalTask ProjectName="$(MSBuildProjectName)"
ProjectDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"
ProjectFullPath="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
SolutionPath="$(SolutionDir)"> 


can someone help please?
